# Theme is not working on checkout in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I install the magneto themes, after add the product on the magento admin panel, i proceed the checkout process, but not displayed the themes  checkout, it will display the default checkout process, how to solve this problem

Comment: is your theme loading on home page and kindly enable the log from backend check what you are getting in system.log or exception.log

Comment: If it is a new theme you installed then please clear your magento and browser cache then check if any option new theme is providing to enable that option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: The theme could be defaulting to the "base" or "default" skin folders because it's not finding what it wants. Compare and see if something is missing or try overwriting any of these and see what happens.